# How can I make an AWS server act as part of a local network?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, vpn, vlan, hamachi

I am the it admin for my wife's architectural office, and so far things have been running pretty smoothly for the 3 person office using various Cloud and P2P solutions, avoiding servers and hardware as long as possible. But now I have a need for a dedicated server to serve as

1. CodeMeter licensing server for ArchiCad
2. Always-on read-only sync peer for Resilio Sync to have sync capabilities off-hours for remote work

This server will be a virtual one running on AWS. The actual setup and of those things is fine, but I was wondering how I can best make that server act as part of the local network without exposing it to the public? I would like to keep it behind AWS firewalls, so I am guessing some kind of VPN solution is needed. Or is there other ways of doing this that I should be aware of? Have been looking at [Hamachi](http://vpn.net/) for the VPN/VLAN part, but not sure how well it works. Really hoping to find a solution where people don't need to manually activate some VPN solution, but where it *just works (tm)*.

Comment: A VPN solution is most likely what you want for sure. Take a look at openvpn too.

Comment: Yeah, but ease of use is really high on the priority, and OpenVPN is a pain to configure and setup. Hamachi is really simple, and cheaper for hosted solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup a site-to-site VPN tunnel between the office and AWS. That way you can access the server on an internal IP through the VPN.

It won't be the same local network, but it will be close.

[Amazon has a great writeup on it here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_VPN.html)

Comment: That's fine, but I also need to support people on mobile connections

Comment: @oligofren What's the problem with that? Put it in your question.

Comment: @oligofren In that case you should just make a VPN solution from the mobile connection to the office. Depending on your firewall the difficulty depends. This site is not for product recommendations, so I won't give any specific, but there are some out there that are pretty easy to setup and configure.